# Node Js Image Upload Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to upload the image to server using node js.The image is coming from ios app as a file data. I have used the following code,

```
 var fs = require("fs");
    var imageName = req.files.profile_image.name;
    fs.readFile(req.files.profile_image.path, function (err, data) {
    console.log(imageName);
    // If there's an error
    if(!imageName){
      console.log("There was an error")
      //res.redirect("/");
      //res.end();
    } else {
        console.log(data);
      var newPath = 'http://example.com/images/' + imageName;
      // write file to uploads/fullsize folder
      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
        // let's see it
        console.log(err);
        //res.redirect("http://example.com/images/" + imageName);
      });
    }
  });
```

When I run this code, I have received no error but the image is not uploaded in images folder.

I am getting the following error with fs.writeFile,

```
   { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://example.com/images/user-profile.jpg'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'http://example.com/images/user-profile.jpg' }
```

Please help.

Comment: can be file write permission issue in your server

Comment: TypeError: fs.move is not a function I am getting. How to check the permission issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with error.Please have a look

Comment: @ Subburaj File permission is 777

Comment: 'http://example.com/user-profile.jpg' It should be 'http://example.com/images/user-profile.jpg' right?? In your error statement its without /image..

Comment: It is a typing mistake here.I have corrected it

Comment: `http://example.com/images/user-profile.jpg` is not a valid file system path. Why are you trying to save the file with a hard-coded domain in url format? Is that a mistake or do you want/need it like that for some reason? Saving the file with that name won't make it available from that url...

Comment: @cviejo Thanks. That was the issue. I used __dirname and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write the image you are receiving as an url ...
It should be a local path on the server that is running your application.

```
fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
  // ...
  var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/uploadedFileName";
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    res.redirect("back");
  });
});
```

Also do not re-write the image into its new path, but instead move it (with rename()):

```
fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
  // ...
  var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/uploadedFileName";

  fs.rename(files.upload.path, _path +'/'+ img_name + '.png', function (error) {
    res.redirect("back");
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use this in the app.js

app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

Comment: This is useful for [serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), but the question is about file uploads.